# Mule SFDC Connector without user interaction using sfdc:config-with-oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying to access Salesforce through my Mule flows using "sfdc:config-with-oauth". Is there any way I can achieve this without redirecting the user to a Login page? I know there is a SSO login dance which I have to do manually, but was hoping it was simpler than that. I found this documentation http://mulesoft.github.io/salesforce-connector/mule/sfdc-config-with-oauth.html. It shows "sfdc:authorize/", but that is not accurate. sfdc:authorize has DISPLAY as a required attribute. What is the meaning of "IMMEDIATE" attribute? Is it possible, somehow, to give Username/Password along with Consumer Key/Secret to "sfdc:config-with-oauth"?

My Mule flow already has User credentials.

I am using Mule Studio 3.5.0

I have also asked the question on salesforce.stacktrace but no response. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34693/mule-sfdc-connector-without-user-interaction-using-sfdcconfig-with-oauth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SFDC connector without OAuth:

http://mulesoft.github.io/salesforce-connector/6.1.0/mule/sfdc-config.html

You can then configure username and password in the connector's config.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the response. I looked at the above link many times, but was not sure how the auth worked. If I have multiple sub-flows and have SFDC calls within each flow, does the oauth happen only once? What about multiple calls to the same flow? Does each call initiate an authentication request to Salesforce?

Comment: If you decide to use OAuth (I thought you didn't want to), then no: the OAuth dance happens only once. After that the access token is cached. Not sure if SFDC supports refresh tokens so a regular dance may be needed to ensure the freshness of the access token.

Comment: Thanks David. I am open for any option. Sorry if my post is misleading. Essentially, I want a way to cleanly access SFDC without user interaction. I also don't want to autheticate on every call because it is needless. I was hoping there was a way some token is cached in mule, unless it becomes invalid at SFDC. We have achieved this funcationality using J2EE code, but was wondering if there is something out of the box in Mule. I will accept your answer since it does provide me one way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Yes there's a token cache. If you use the OAuth SFDC connector, you will not be able to achieve "cleanly access SFDC without user interaction". When you say "I don't want to autheticate on every call because it is needless" do you mean "a user" or "the Mule application"?

Comment: I do not want my Mule applicaiton to authenticate with SFDC on each call. The first call to my mule flow should perform the oAuth dance and store the token (in objectstore maybe?). All subsequent calls should know the token exists and use it. If the token expires at SFDC for some reason, Mule flow should be smart enough to redo the oAuth dance and get a new token. I am no SFDC expert (yet) but I did read that it supports Refresh tokens.

Comment: OK so if you're fine with having a user interaction to initiate the OAuth dance then disregard my answer.

Comment: @DavidDossot,  I having same problem, I want to use mule scheduler with oauth, how do I achieve this without user interaction? my requirement is an event will trigger at 10am by scheduler and data publishes to SFDC. I can use basic authentication, is it possible to use oauth without user interaction since it is scheduler event and not http requests. Above link given by you is broken.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the link. SFDC API exposes endpoints that do not need an OAuth token. Check the Mule doc here http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Salesforce+Connector and consult the SFDC API doc as well.